# How does the struct of a linked list know the type of next pointer of its own type?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

```
struct node
{
    int     data;
    node*   pointerToNextNode;
};
```

Here `pointerToNextNode` is the type of `struct node`, and it is declared inside the struct.
How does the struct know the type of next pointer of its own type - when it itself hasn't been formed yet?

There is no keyword `extern` used. How does this work?

Comment: if `private` was intended as an access specifier, then C doesn't work like that.

Comment: @ArjunSreedharan sorry, that was typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here `pointerToNextNode` is the type of `struct node`

No, it's not. It's of type `struct node *`

`struct node*   pointerToNextNode;` allocates memory for a **pointer** variable of type `struct node`.
It does not allocate memory for `struct node`, so, till point, it does not need to know about the size and representation of `struct node`. Only the (data)type name is sufficient.

Also, it's worthy to mention, without a `typedef` in place, `node*   pointerToNextNode;` should not be valid. It should be written like below

```
typedef struct node node; 

struct node 
{ 
    int data; 
    node* pointerToNextNode; 
};
```

BTW, `private:` is not `C` thing, if i'm not wrong.

Comment: yeah, that `private` thing was typo. Sorry. Could you please show the proper way of writing that code with typedef in place?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius try something like `typedef struct node node;

struct node
{
    int     data;
    node*   pointerToNextNode;
};`

Comment: You should never bother with typedefs for structs. They are useless. They only save you from writing `struct` in a few places, which is information that should **not** be lost.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't need to know the structure, it's enough to know the type name, namely `struct node` — and that has already been defined.

Same result you can obtain by forward type declaration:

```
struct node;            // declare the struct not defining it
struct node *pointer;   // declare variable

void foo()
{
    if(pointer != NULL)        // OK, we use the pointer only
        if(pointer->x == 0)    // invalid use - struct contents unknown yet
            return;
}

struct node {           // supply a definition
    int x;
};

void bar()
{
    if(pointer != NULL)
        if(pointer->x == 0)    // OK - struct contents already known
            return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for me this doesn't compile using CC -- and exactly because of what you said.
you would have to use `struct node *` to make the compiler aware you want memory for a **pointer**